# How to install lsof on Debian/kFreeBSD?

Tags: debian, freebsd, apt-get, lsof

How do you install lsof on Debian/kFreeBSD Testing (Wheezy/Sid)?

```
$ apt-get install lsof
Package lsof is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'lsof' has no installation candidate
```

Edit:
/etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian/ testing main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org testing/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org testing/updates main contrib non-free
```

Comment: All debian boxes that I've used had it installed by default (Ubuntu, primarily. The true debian boxes that I use are down at the moment, so I can't confirm with them, but I didn't have to tell them to install `lsof`).

Comment: Maybe `lsof` only works on Linux and not kFreeBSD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `lsof` is not part of the kFreeBSD variant of Debian as
can be confirmed here: [Debian software search](http://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=lsof&mode=exactfilename&suite=stable&arch=kfreebsd-i386)

Maybe [sockstat](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/sockstat) can be helpful in this context. Sockstat gives you information
about the opened sockets like which process/command is using it.